# Parody of a Parody

Tags: expressions

I recently became aware of this video:

[What has the ECHR ever done for us](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptfmAY6M6aA)

Which, to me, is clearly a parody of this scene from Monty Python's Life of Brian - itself a Parody of the new testament.

[What have the romans ever done for us](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExWfh6sGyso)

Which got me thinking, is there a name for a Parody of a Parody? The term self-parody does not seem to fit - as that tends to reference parodying ones own work or oneself.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I had not considered that. An answer pointing out that I have mislabelled that would get a tick from me.

Comment: I would personally suggest that the phrase 'clearly a parody' may be too broad, as I would personally find The Life of Brian to be a subtly fictionalised take on the existing scripture, which might in certain places also bear resemblance to actual events, though of course this may not be everyone's view and it seems more a comic retelling than an exaggeration. Also, generally a parody represents a 'send-up' or even an amusing attack on an established work... And to my view we are laughing *with* scripture and *with* Jesus's situation, rather than at him. That's my personal take anyway.

Comment: Lessee -- either a quadrody or a trirody -- I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 2):

> Which got me thinking, is there a name for a Parody of a Parody? The term self-parody does not seem to fit - as that tends to reference parodying ones own work or oneself.

In this case, I think the ECHR version may be more of an *homage* to "The Life of Brian."

From http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079470/quotes:

> **Reg:** All right, but apart from the sanitation, medicine, education, wine, public order, irrigation, roads, the fresh water system and public health, what have the Romans ever done for us?
>
> **Attendee:** Brought peace?
>
> **Reg:** Oh, peace - shut up!
>
> **Reg:** There is not one of us who would not gladly suffer death to rid this country of the Romans once and for all.
>
> **Dissenter:** Uh, well, one.
>
> **Reg:** Oh, yeah, yeah, there's one. But otherwise, we're solid.

However, as lovely and appropriate the word *homage* is, it fails to answer your question. While getting ready for my day another thought came to me and I found the following at http://www.britannica.com/art/parody-literature:

> "Another innovation was **double parody**, invented by Sir John Squire in the period between World Wars I and II; it is the rendering of the sense of one poet in the style of another—e.g., Squire’s version of Thomas Gray’s 'An Elegy Written in a Country Churchyard' written in the style of Edgar Lee Masters’s Spoon River Anthology resulted in 'If Gray Had Had to Write His Elegy in the Cemetery of Spoon River Instead of in That of Stoke Poges.'”